# how to update a primary key in Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

We have the following table

table1:companies

```
id_pk | name
------+------- 
1     | company1
2     | company2
3     | newcompany
```

id is the primary key

table2:toys

```
id_pk | name_pk  
------+-------
1     | toy1
2     | toy2
```

table 2 uses the primary key of table 1 as part of its primary key,

table3:clients

```
Cid_pk  | name_fk | id_fk
-------+----------+------
1x     | toy1     | 1
2x     | toy2     | 2
```

table 3 uses as foreign key the primary keys of table2, name and id

I have to update all entries of table2 to id=3 but sql doesn't allow me to do that. This is the desired result:

```
id_pk | name_pk  
------+-------
3     | toy1
3     | toy2



Cid_pk  | name_fk | id_fk
-------+----------+------
1x     | toy1     | 3
2x     | toy2     | 3
```

How can I do it? Should I use update cascade? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps showing your desired results would be helpful.  As is, it's difficult to understand your intentions.  Why would you want to update all ids in the toys table to 3?  A primary key has to be unique.

Comment: I think you need to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Primary keys are meant to be unique identifiers to each row.  It would make no sense to make those the same -- you simply cannot do that and I'm not positive why you'd want to.

Answer (score 0):

For updating primary keys remove foreign keys, after update add foriegn key constraint again.